# How do I load all segments / chunks for a video? especially segments before the current one

Tags: video, html5-video, media-source, hls.js

SHORT QUESTION

With hls.js how do I load all segments / chunks for a video? (even if the current video time is not at the start of the video)

QUESTION WITH BACKGROUND

I switch currentLevel with hls.js like so:

```
private setBestQuality() {
  this.player.hls.currentLevel = this.hlsLevelsCount - 1
}

private setWorstQuality() {
  this.player.hls.currentLevel = 0
}
```

This is standard stuff and does an (almost) immediate level switch. The reason I am doing this is because I noticed that when scrubbing/seeking, the player is much more responsive when using a low quality level. When scrubbing/seeking starts I switch to the lowest available quality level and when it ends I then switch back to the highest quality level.

One issue though, when I switch to low quality, let's assume the video currentTime is 30/60 seconds. Hls.js will buffer the current chunk/segment and the next segment but it does not buffer earlier segments in the video. As a result, when scrubbing backwards, there's a little jerk whilst the unbuffered chunk loads.

Is there any way to force hls.js to load all chunks? These chunks are small and the videos are short so the time taken to load/buffer all the chunks should not be too much of a concern.

STACKBLITZ TO DEMO THE PROBLEM

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmu8py - EDIT

https://angular-ivy-pmu8py.stackblitz.io - FULL SCREEN WITHOUT CODE

Basically this proves that scrubbing backwards on **lowest quality** when all frags are loaded is very smooth (but NOT when all frags are NOT loaded).

Comment: Associated github issue here https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/4745

Comment: Why is HLS (with MSE) needed for short clips? What does it achieve that, where simply loading the video data into Arrays, to play in a `<video>` tag is not enough? PS: I assume you know FFmpeg? (In case the answer to solve jerkiness in seeking might involve a re-encoding of video clips to a certain setting).

Comment: we've done a lot of testing and integration with hls.js and it meets our need - not going to turn away from hls.js now over this one issue - 500 rep says I would like to fix this issue - however, thanks for the thought

Comment: You say _"I would like to fix this issue"_ Give us a starting point. Please **show some testable code that recreates your problem**. A simple demo code (of video player page?) whose job is to show your HLS.js problem in action. Providing 2 testable videos (high and low quality) would also help or maybe just provide us an FFmpeg command to recreate your own clips' encoder settings, if possible... Solutions could be based on adjusting your HLS.js code or by adjusting your video encoding settings. the "encoder" part is because of seeking backwards. It might be a new issue after loading is fixed.

Comment: This StackBlitz recreates the problem - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmu8py

Comment: @VC.One I am familiar with ffmpeg and have used it before, but for the purposes of this project the HLS chunks and the .m3u8 file is created by a third party and I have little control over it - Stackblitz added to question to aid reproduction of the problem ... One solution is to have 2 players, one for high quality (playback) and one for low quality (scrubbing) and only display one on screen, the other would be off screen or hidden - this would fix the buffering issue caused by dynamically switching quality levels but is a workaround and I am trying to avoid this approach if possible

Comment: OK. I see the stackBlitz. I will see what I can do to help you. Basically you want [this type of effect or result](https://jordicenzano.github.io/frame-accurate-scrubbing/ui/player/example_player.html?m=../../media/transcoded/testSimpleV1/854x480/main_manifest.json), right? That guy used JPEG per frame (ouch) because no-one told him it could be done with H264 that has **keyframe-only** frames. This is what I meant about possible re-encoding. Why have low quality when a 480p or 720p could be scrolled smoothly too (if keyframes-only)... Anyways, let me read up on HLS.js to try my tricks...

Comment: yeah that's exactly what I'm after, scrubbing that's uber-smooth. Thanks ever so much for looking into this, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: No worries but I won't have an answer in time for your bounty deadline. It'll take a day or two. I got a result from my own fragmented MP4 in chunks (skipping the need to make HLS.js remux the `.ts` files into frag-MP4 for MSE playback). When I get a chance I will check how to get HLS.js to give back the remuxed TS chunks (not auto-append them to MSE) so that I can manually store the data in an Array and later the seeking part can get it's buffers from the array. I need to make HLS.js read from the stored array, not loading external files...